# Build Context fails trying to build Spring / React application

Tags: spring-boot, docker

I'm essentially trying to use a docker container to build my React Frontend and put it inside the static resource folder of my Spring backend. I'm new to Docker and am getting a `failed to solve : error from sender: context canceled.` It was building yesterday, but when I went to run `docker compose up --build` it has been giving me this error.

### Docker File:

```
 # Build the React frontend
FROM node:latest as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
#Connection to put the package.json into the app/
COPY FrontEnd/package*.json /app/
RUN npm install
COPY FrontEnd/ /app/
RUN npm run build

# Build the Spring Boot application
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-slim as build-app
WORKDIR /app

# Install xargs using apt-get, since Ubuntu uses apt
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y findutils && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /app/src/main/resources/static
COPY . /app/
RUN chmod +x gradlew
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y dos2unix && dos2unix gradlew
RUN find ./ -name "*.java" | xargs dos2unix
RUN ./gradlew build -x test

# Prepare the runtime container
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-slim
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-app /app/build/libs/*.jar /app/app.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]
```

### Docker Compose yml:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  postgres-dev-db:
    container_name: assignment5
    image: "postgres"
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: assignment5
    volumes:
      - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5455:5432"

  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - postgres-dev-db
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:postgresql://postgres-dev-db:5432/assignment5
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: postgres
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: postgres
```

Results from running `docker build .`

```
    docker build .   
[+] Building 9.9s (7/22)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      docker:desktop-linux
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 908B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/openjdk:17-jdk-slim                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        0.6s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:latest                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.6s
 => [build-stage 1/6] FROM docker.io/library/node:latest@sha256:0052410af98158173b17a26e0e2a46a3932095ac9a0ded660439a8ffae65b1e3                                                                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => [build-app  1/10] FROM docker.io/library/openjdk:17-jdk-slim@sha256:aaa3b3cb27e3e520b8f116863d0580c438ed55ecfa0bc126b41f68c3f62f9774                                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => CANCELED [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    8.7s
 => => transferring context: 171.30MB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         8.5s
ERROR: failed to solve: error from sender: context canceled
```

[image]

Comment: share the entire error

Comment: try just doing a `docker build .` on the image and share the output

Comment: Just added the result of docker build  .